# Empty Ant <junitreport> report for SoapUI testrunner XML results

Tags: junit, ant, soapui, ant-junit

I am running a SoapUI project using Ant to get a JUnit report.

Here is my build.xml:

```
<project basedir="." default="testreport" name="APIAutomation">
<target name="SoapUI">
    <exec dir="." executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\testrunner.bat">
        <arg line="-r -j -a -f 'C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder' -sFirstLoginTest 'C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\APIRegression.xml'"></arg>
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="testreport" depends="SoapUI">
    <junitreport todir="C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames"
            todir="C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\reports\html">
        </report>
    </junitreport>
</target>
</project>
```

I am getting an XML report properly. However, the JUnit report is empty. `all` contains 0 and `successrate` is `Nan`.

Can anyone check the build.xml is correct?

Comment: Do you see the `TEST*.xml` file under `C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API` directory? Do you find `index.html` file?

Comment: TEST*.xml is seeing in C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\API.. index.html is in C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\reports\html

Comment: How may test cases there in the suite? How is index.html is appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Looks build script seems ok
- Avoid spaces in the directory names
- Use forward slashes like unix style even on windows
- Use property file or properties in build script so that other members do not have it edit the build scripts as paths might change machine to machine.
- For now, added properties in the below script, you may externalize to a property file too.

**build.xml**

```
<project basedir="." default="testreport" name="APIAutomation">
   <property name="test.suite" value="FirstLoginTest"/>
   <property name="soapui.project" value="C:/Users/F3020722/Desktop/Notification/New folder/APIRegression.xml"/>
   <property name="soapui.home" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.0.0"/>
   <property name="results.dir" value="C:/Users/F3020722/Desktop/Notification/API/Results"/>
   <property name="reports.dir" value="${results.dir}/Reports"/>
   <property name="html.dir" value="${reports.dir}/html"/>
   <target name="execute.project">
     <exec dir="${soapui.home}/bin" executable="testrunner.bat">
        <arg line="-raj -f ${results.dir} -s ${test.suite} ${soapui.project}" />
     </exec>
  </target>
   <target name="testreport" depends="execute.project">
        <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}"/>
            <junitreport todir="${reports.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${results.dir}">
                    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
                </fileset>
                <report format="frames" todir="${html.dir}" />
            </junitreport>
   </target>
</project>
```

You can also find a docker image for soapui and run tests & generate junit style html report as well. Refer [soapui repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/nmrao/soapui/) @ hub.docker.com

**Note:** that build script used docker images is exactly the same as above except the machine path.

Comment: Thanks Rao.. I will try the edited build file and update you.

Comment: Getting following error.. But the path for testrunner.bat is correct.. Buildfile: C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\build.xml

execute.project:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\F3020722\Desktop\Notification\New folder\build.xml:10: Execute failed:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "testrunner.bat" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I wish you could follow the pointers that i mentioned in the answer. Mainly remove empty spaces in file and directory names.