# Junit empty reports while running soapui testsuites using ant

Tags: junit, ant, soapui

I am trying to run my testsuite using ant, for reporting I am using ant.

I did a lot of tries but unable to get the reports. My test suite is running properly, but my Junit report all values are 0.

My Build xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project basedir="." default="testreport" name="Automation">
    <property name="results.dir" value="D:/airline.com/NDC_Automation/API/Results"/>
    <property name="reports.dir" value="${results.dir}/Reports"/>
    <property name="html.dir" value="${reports.dir}/html"/>
    <property name="proj.dir" value="D:/airline.com/NDC_Automation/Project/ADC-NDC-SB8-soapui-project.xml"/>
    <target name="testsuite1">
        <exec dir="." executable="D:/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.bat">
        <arg line="-r -j -a -f ${results.dir} -sDAC-3728 ${proj.dir}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="testreport" depends="testsuite1">
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}"/>
    <junitreport todir="${reports.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${results.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.XML"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${html.dir}">
        </report>
    </junitreport>
</target>
</project>
```

I followed another post from stackoveflow[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117320/empty-ant-junitreport-report-for-soapui-testrunner-xml-results) and followed the steps mentioned in it as well. But still my junit report is empty.

My TESTS-TestSuites.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites />
```

Is my build file correct or have i missed any important tag ?

Comment: Rajesh, can you please double check the paths, and test suite name?

Comment: The test suite name is correct, because my cases are running and i am able to see the request and responses saved.

Comment: It is really strange. The other guy (from linked post) saying it worked.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to help me via screen share or webex ?

Comment: Can you join here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152543/room-for-rao-and-ragesh-kr